# Rotate (group) objects outwards on spherical particle system?

Tags: particles, groups

I'm trying to create a mini-world with (among other things) trees on it. I have created an icosphere, modeled several trees and put them in a group.
Next I added a particle system to the sphere, and chose hair. In the "render" section I selected *Group* and the name of the group I created. As expected the trees show up but they're all oriented in the same direction, while I would like them to pop up just like the default hairs do (along the normal of the individual faces).
I tried fiddling with all kinds of settings, had them oriented in all kind of ways (e.g. towards the "north pole"). I also tried using the emitter instead of hair setting but without success as well.

Comment: David and gandalf3 thanks for your help! Much appreciated! Rotating the tree along the x-axis in edit-mode seems to be the crucial step I was missing, but it works now :) I tried to accept both your answers but apparently that's not possible? (I'm new here so I might be missing something ;))

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Yes, you can only accept one. You can vote for as many as you want though. Feel free to [take the tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) or visit the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your hair particle system, just click on the button `Rotation` in the render panel of the particle settings.

[image]

Then make sure your objects are pointing towards the `X` axis. Other wise all your trees will point out from your planet, but they will not be pointing up.
[image].

Answer (score 5):

Try rotating the source objects instead of trying to correct the rotation in the particle settings.

Note that the particle position is based on the *Object origin*, so make sure your origins are at the bases of your trees.

By default object rotation will not affect particles, so either:

- Rotate the tree objects in edit mode, or rotate in object mode (individual origins is useful for rotating multiple objects at once) and then apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)

  Without *rotation* enabled in the particle settings, it appears that objects are oriented with the `+Y` direction facing out (with *rotation* enabled it is `+X`).

  [image]
- Rotate in object mode and enable rotation in *Particle settings > Render* (as [already mentioned by David](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8106/599))

## Result:

[image]