# Align particle to object normals?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, particles, normals

Trying to put these objects (as particle objects) onto a slightly deformed tube model. This is it so far, but as you can see the rotation of the objects is different depending on the vertex it is placed on, and I'd like them all "pointing" in the X direction . I've applied rotation, scale, etc, for all objects, made sure normals are aligned correctly, etc. Second image is what I mean (done manually).

Related particle settings go as follows: 
Emit from verts
No physics
Render object is the tile
Rotation is enabled with initial rotation as "normal".
Rotation is enabled in render tab as well.

Please help, and ask if any other specifics are required.
Cheers.

[image]

[image: image of smaller cylinder was done manually to show what I mean]

Comment: Little unclear on _" I'd like them all "pointing" in the X direction"_  Could you add an image with a couple of manually placed showing desired result to clarify.

Comment: Is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8104/2217) what you want to do?

Comment: Have edited post to show what I mean (manually placed), the tutorial David posted is one I followed but I couldn't get it to work.